# wordpress ajaxy live search display error

Tags: wordpress, livesearch

I've got Display Problems with the Ajaxy Live search Plugin.

When I search something on my Homepage it's showing all post results like this:

[On my Homepage](https://owncloud.hsr.ch/public.php?service=files&t=0815051f78e107e8fdea05d96ccbd374)

But it should look like this:

[wp-admin preview](https://owncloud.hsr.ch/public.php?service=files&t=70815036e3e4bd475535e05757cc3ca2)

It's displayed correctly in a preview from ajaxy live search in wp-admin.
Has anyone got an idea what this Problem causes?

Comment: your images are hosted on a forum that needs registration to view. that's not helpful at all.

Comment: Ohh i'm sorry didn't recognize that

Here's the first Picture: https://owncloud.hsr.ch/public.php?service=files&t=0815051f78e107e8fdea05d96ccbd374

...and the second Picture: https://owncloud.hsr.ch/public.php?service=files&t=70815036e3e4bd475535e05757cc3ca2

Comment: if you inspect the element in chrome/firefox with firebug you'll probably see some css that you can change to fix this. - i suggest it's just some css overflow issues.

Comment: I found the damn Problem... it's the Internet Explorer! Everythings working fine on Firefox and Chrome tho. I just enlarged the live-search by that much that no scroll-bar is showing up anymore. Now ist also working fine in the IE. The Overflow is set to auto

Comment: add your comment and and code changes as an answer and you can get some points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my Workaround (forgot to Post earlier):

Open "\wp-content\plugins\ajaxy-search-form\themes\common.css"
and find

`.sf_result_container {
    max-height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}`

I changed `max-height:200px;` to `max-height:100%;`. Now the live-search is enlarged untill to the end of all search results and doesn't overlap anymore.